# Get every size ID, within list of variants

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this list I want to get every ID from variants. I would need to for each loop this? Here is what I have for code

List: https://kith.com/collections/footwear-women/products/nike-air-vapormax-flyknit-moc-2-black-light-cream-white.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'https://kith.com/collections/footwear-women/products/nike-air-vapormax-flyknit-moc-2-black-light-cream-white.js';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        alert(data.variants[0].id);
        var x = (data.variants[0].id);
        console.log(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: "I would need to for each loop this? " Seems like you answered your question.

Comment: @SplySply JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. It is a way to represent javascript object as strings. You can parse JSON into javascript but you cannot do ANYTHING else with JSON. According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) the `getJSON` success argument supplies a `PlainObject`. Your question is about Javascript, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to iterate over the response, which is what in the below example `$.map` is doing but you could also use a `for` loop or a `foreach` call on the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'https://kith.com/collections/footwear-women/products/nike-air-vapormax-flyknit-moc-2-black-light-cream-white.js';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.variants, function(index, value) {
      console.log('id:', value.id);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not how `$.map` should be used. It's intended for building an array from the value you should be returning from the function. If you want to do it this way, use `each()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the information, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options when it comes to iterating an array. Here's an example of the most basic method, using a simple `for` loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = 'https://kith.com/collections/footwear-women/products/nike-air-vapormax-flyknit-moc-2-black-light-cream-white.js';
   $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      var numberOfVariants = data.variants.length;
      var ids = [];
      for(var i=0;i<numberOfVariants;i++){
        var id = data.variants[i].id;
        ids.push(id);
      }
      console.log(ids);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop, although you can use an implicit one, such as provided by  `map()`, to create the array from the `id` properties in the `variants` array:

```js
$(function() {
  var url = 'https://kith.com/collections/footwear-women/products/nike-air-vapormax-flyknit-moc-2-black-light-cream-white.js';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var variantIds = data.variants.map(v => v.id);
    console.log(variantIds);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```